# Marriage rate among different age groups in European countries?

Tags: data-request, europe

I'm looking for data to list the marriage rate of all or most of European countries by different age group. For example:

- Sweden 25-29 32%
- Sweden 30-34 65%
- Sweden 35-39 82%
- Denmark 25-29 35%
- Denmark 30-34 70%

....

It would be better if it is split by gender. But as far as I search on the Internet, it seems common that in European countries, the marriage rate is calculated by the total number of marriages in the year divided by 1,000, which is not I'm looking for.

So is there any such statistics on European countries (possibly EU)?

Comment: Perhaps you could combine data sources mentioned [here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php/Marriage_and_birth_statistics_-_new_ways_of_living_together_in_the_EU) (esp. `cens_11ms_r3`) with population data.